# Stored Procedure betwee particular date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to do the Following in SQL:

Create a stored procedure called usp_orders_by_dates displaying the orders shipped between
particular dates. The start and end date will be input parameters for the stored procedure.

My Code looks like follow:

CREATE PROC usp_orders_by_dates
  @date DATETIME
  AS
  BEGIN

```
  SELECT
  o.OrderID
  ,o.CustomerID
  ,c.CompanyName AS CustomerCompany
  ,s.ShipperID
  ,s.Company AS ShipperCompany
  ,@date AS ShippedDate

  FROM Orders o
  INNER JOIN Customer c
      ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
  INNER JOIN Shippers s    
      ON o.ShipperID = s.ShipperID

  ORDER BY
    ShipperDate
```

END

IF I run the following Command I should receive back a Range in The ShippedDate:
   EXEC usp_orders_by_dates '1991-07-01', '1991-08-01'

Comment: Based on your scenario, you will need a second input parameter for the end of the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your `Stored Procedure` is missing the second `EndDate` parameter.

Second, you do not have any `WHERE` condition that filters for the `ShippedDate`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_orders_by_dates 
    @dateStart DATETIME,
    @dateEnd DateTime 
AS
    SELECT
    o.OrderID
    ,o.CustomerID
    ,c.CompanyName AS CustomerCompany
    ,s.ShipperID
    ,s.Company AS ShipperCompany
    ,@date AS ShippedDate

    FROM Orders o
    INNER JOIN Customer c
        ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN Shippers s    
        ON o.ShipperID = s.ShipperID
      WHERE ShipperDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    ORDER BY
      ShipperDate
```

Attention: You should be very careful with BETWEEN especially for dates. If you want to search dates between 01.01.2013 and 31.12.2013 (including) then you should use `WHERE BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2014-01-01'`. It is even better to use `WHERE Date >= '2013-01-01' AND Date < '2014-01-01'`. The former will include the Timestamp `2014-01-01 00:00:00000` the latter will exclude this.

Comment: [Be very careful about BETWEEN](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx).

Comment: I have added a short description to my answer.

Comment: It is still wrong, for three reasons: (1) BETWEEN midnight on jan 1 2013 and midnight on jan 1 2014 will include all orders in 2013 *and* any orders on jan 1 2014 that happened to have been posted at midnight. (2) You should never use ambiguous, regional date formats like `dd.mm.yyyy`. (3) You should not enclose date/string literals in double quotes - SQL Server is going to think those are columns.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `@dateEnd` parameter probably is a round date, and your OrderDate column could include time, be very careful about using `BETWEEN` or `>= AND <=` constructs. These will include only orders at midnight on the last day in the range, and nothing from 0:00:00.003 on. [You should always use an open-ended range (and add a day to the end when necessary)](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Also, be very careful about not using a schema prefix when you create or reference objects. [This can lead to all kinds of hard-to-solve issues](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).

Finally, the parameters should be `DATE` so that any time is truncated and you don't have to worry about partial days because someone decided to use `GETDATE()` for one of the parameters.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_orders_by_dates 
    @dateStart DATE,
    @dateEnd   DATE 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT
    o.OrderID
    ,o.CustomerID
    ,c.CompanyName AS CustomerCompany
    ,s.ShipperID
    ,s.Company AS ShipperCompany
    ,@date AS ShippedDate

    FROM dbo.Orders AS o
    INNER JOIN dbo.Customer AS c -- why is Orders plural, but not Customers?
        ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN dbo.Shippers AS s -- Shippers is plural too. Inconsistent.   
        ON o.ShipperID = s.ShipperID
      WHERE ShipperDate >= @startDate 
      AND   ShipperDate <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, @endDate) 
    ORDER BY
      ShipperDate;
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROC usp_orders_by_dates
@startdate DATETIME,
@enddate DATETIME 
AS BEGIN
  SELECT
  o.OrderID
  ,o.CustomerID
  ,c.CompanyName AS CustomerCompany
  ,s.ShipperID
  ,s.Company AS ShipperCompany
  ,s.ShippedDate

  FROM Orders o
  INNER JOIN Customer c
      ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
  INNER JOIN Shippers s    
      ON o.ShipperID = s.ShipperID

WHERE s.shippeddate >= @startdate AND
s.shippeddate <= @enddate

  ORDER BY
    s.ShippedDate

END
```

Comment: The code formatting from my phone is terrible. I'll clean up the formatting when I get to my desk. I concur with the other answer as it is the same but formatted nicer.

Comment: [Be very careful about >= and <= (which is the same as BETWEEN)](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx).

Comment: Aaron - Do you recommend BETWEEN instead?

Comment: NO. Please read [the link](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx) (or [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20115775/61305)). >= and <= is the exact same thing as BETWEEN.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification. Missed your answer as I hadn't refreshed my phone. I figured your concern was for the many possible syntax errors, but I was unsure if I was missing a perf or security issue as well. I appreciate your answer above. :-)